# Flight compensation

Tags: delays, compensation

I am querying whether I am entitled to compensation for a flight delay.

My British Airways flight on 01 March 2018 (London Heathrow to Washington Dulles) was cancelled. I was originally due to arrive at 2:55 PM.

I was rebooked onto an American Airlines flight via Charlotte, NC, with an estimated arrival time in Washington of 3:56 PM. This was delayed and I did not arrive in Washington under 6:06pm.

Am I entitled to any compensation?

Comment: When was it cancelled? https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm might be helpful here.

Comment: What was the cause of the cancellation? When were you notified? You may be entitled to a €300 compensation, but this depends on the details.

Comment: Note that regardless of whether you are entitled to compensation, you are entitled to having reasonable additional expenses reimbursed.

Answer (score 1):

The details provided by you does not seem to be sufficient but as you mentioned that your flight were cancelled then you may entitle to claim compensation from the airline; if they did not notify you about the cancellation prior 7 days of your departure provided that you should not have chosen the option of alternative flight.

If you have chosen the option of alternative flight and that alternative flight delays for more than 3 hours then you may entitle to claim compensation. You can use online flight delay compensation calculator here: https://www.claimflights.co.uk/claim-now to check whether you are eligible to claim compensation or not.

Also, you can refer this link: http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:52016XC0615(01) to know about your air passenger rights in details.